# C++ container of any/variant each element having unchanging type

Tags: c++, boost-variant, boost-any

I am using `std::map<const char*, boost::any>` to store my library's settings.  Each setting only uses a single underlying value type and I want to enforce this during configuration calls to `set()` or similar. Settings are initialized with default values of the correct type.

Here is some pseudo code that hopefully shows what I'm trying to achieve:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

void set(map<const char *, any> &settings, const char *key, any &value)
{
    if (type_of(value) != type_of(settings[key]) throw wrong_type_exception();
    settings[key] = value;
}
```

Is it possible to trap type errors like this at runtime?  I'd prefer not to have template functions in my API if possible.

I've used `boost::any` but might consider boost::variant's `which()` if that's the only viable solution.

Answer (score 2):

`value.type() != settings[key].type()`

If `settings[key]` doesn't previously exist, then `settings[key].type()` is `typeid(void)`, which compares equal to `value.type()` if and only if `value` is empty. So you won't be able to add new setting/value pairs via this function, but based on the pseudo-code that seems to be intended.

Comment: Hmm - seems it may not but there is no fundamental reason `boost::any_cast` needs RTTI http://stackoverflow.com/a/2650805/674683

Comment: Seems strange to me, to implement some portion of RTTI (one distinct object per class) in order to avoid RTTI. It just means that when someone uses your code in a program that does have RTTI, they end up with two lots of overhead, the (larger) RTTI overhead plus your (smaller) pseudo-RTTI overhead. But anyway, if you bodge Boost.Any with the modified `typeid` implementation proposed in that anwer, then this code will work without RTTI too.

Comment: I'm not going to modify Any - I think I'm going to use Variant... thanks for your help.

Comment: @paperjam RTTI is an integral part of the language, I don't see why you would want not to use it, and in particular for configuration elements of which there are going to be just a few...

Comment: I don't know enough about RTTI.  Does its overhead apply to all objects in my library or just those whose `typeid` I query?  I guess that's another SO question.