# Creation of unique type ID with c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, unique-id

Why is the following code guaranteed to be a unique typeID ?!

```
using TypeId = uintptr_t; 

template < typename T >
static TypeId GetTypeId()
{
   static uint32_t placeHolder;
   return (reinterpret_cast<TypeId>(&placeHolder));
}
```

[Source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/723656/SW-Message-Bus)

I don't understand why this is not just a kind of random memory location as a kind of "misused"... Thanks for answers in advance.

Comment: The compiler will instantiate a copy of the template function for each type you call it with, and each of these instantiations has its own unique `placeHolder`, so you get a different address for each type.

Comment: _"I don't understand why this is not just a kind of random memory location"_  It is, so to speak.  But that doesn't matter.  It's unique and consistent for each type.

Comment: so I did understand it right, its just a random number that is guaranteed being unique.... is there any advantage in doing this? Is there any kind of advantage in not using RTTI?

Comment: [I used this technique](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2650805/103167) long before that CodeProject article, and I'm not the first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Introduction

You are correct that the implementation abuses the *"random memory location"* of a block-scope *static* variable, but that doesn't mean that the guarantee you are talking about doesn't hold: the returned from `GetTypeId<T>` will be unique for each instantiation of it.

> <sup>**Note**: One should however be aware of the fact that `uintptr_t` is **not** guaranteed to be available for every platform. A fully portable way to implement the function would be to return a `void*`, which is guaranteed to be able to hold every address of every object in a program.</sup>

---

#### The distinct address guarantee...

In *C++* there's a guarantee that every object must reside at a unique address, unless we are talking about an object which is a subobject if another. In such case they may have the same address (and in cases the sharing of address is required, as with standard-layout classes and their first data-member).

> `1.8p6` **The C++ object model** `[intro.object]`
>
> > Unless an object is a bit-field or a base class subobject of zero size, the address of that object is the address of the first byte it occupies. Two objects that are not bit-fields may have the same address if one is a subobject of the other, or if at least one is a base class subobject of zero size and they are of different types; otherwise, **they shall have distinct addresses**.

---

#### Static variables in functions...

We also have an explicit clause saying that every specialization of a function-template that includes a *static* variable has its own unique copy of said static variable:

> `14.8p2` **Function template specializations** `[temp.fct.spec]`
>
> > Each function template specialization instantiated from a template has its own copy of any static variable.

Since a variable that is declared *static* is unique to every instantiation of `GetTypeId<T>`, where `T` is an arbitrary type, every object named `placeHolder` in this template specialization must an unique object.

It must be an unique object, and with that; it must have a distinct address.

---

> <sup>**Note 1)** In *C++11* we have [`std::type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) which fulfils the guarantee you are after.
>  **Note 2)** The *C++11* standard draft [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) has been used as a reference in this post.</sup>